# Postgres error after updating TimescaleDB on Ubuntu: file not found

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.6, timescaledb

As specified in [the official docs](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/getting-started/installation/linux/installation-apt-ubuntu)  I added the Timescale PPA repository to `apt`. I then installed it via `sudo apt install timescaledb-postgresql-9.6`. All was working fine.

With a recent run of `sudo apt upgrade` the timescale package got updated from **0.8.0~ubuntu16.04** to **0.9.1~ubuntu16.04**.

When running my Python script for inserting some new data I now get the following error (and nothing is being inserted):

```
2018-04-12 09:42:06,279 ERROR    Postgres: could not access file "timescaledb-0.8.0": No such file or directory
```

It seems like the old version of the shared library is somewhere still referenced. **Where?**

What I already tried:

- Updating the **psycopg2** Python module I use for access in my script.
- I made sure my `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` still contains `shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'`.
- Restarting the postgres service via `sudo service postgresql restart`.
- Restarting the machine.
- I did a `sudo apt purge timescaledb-postgresql-9.6` followed by reboot, reinstall, service restart.
- When connected to *psql* via `psql -U postgres -h localhost -W` executing the `\dx` command does **not** show timescaledb as an installed extension; so executing `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;` as proposed by the [upgrade docs](https://docs.timescale.com/v0.9/using-timescaledb/update-db) here is not successful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it. `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;` was close - but this has to be executed **on a database** that you are connected to, not globally right after logging on to psql. And it's recommended to also pass the `-X` argument to disable reading the startup file (~/.psqlrc).

1. `psql -X -U postgres -h localhost -W`
2. `\c your-timescale-extended-database-name`
3. `ALTER EXTENSION timescaledb UPDATE;`
4. `\dx`

Output:

```
                                    List of installed extensions
    Name     | Version |   Schema   |                            Description
-------------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
plpgsql     | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
timescaledb | 0.9.1   | public     | Enables scalable inserts and complex queries for time-series data
(2 rows)
```

5. `\q` to quit psql